# Do we need to adopt the custom close reasons from the old meta site here?

Tags: discussion, meta, close-reasons

Before the MSE/MSO split we had the following custom close reasons:

[image: Custom close reasons]

Do we need to adopt any/all of these here or should we wait a while to see which ones might actually be useful?

Comment: We shouldn't need the OT programming question one anymore. Since, IIRC, there's a minimum rep to post on a meta site. And users who post OT questions aren't going to have that.

Comment: Perhaps wait a few weeks to see what kind of closable questions crop up often first?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did think of that as I was writing the post (hence the last line) but thought I'd post anyway.

Comment: Add them now, they can always be changed later if need be.

Comment: I didn't realize they were changed, but I don't see how any of their context has changed.

Comment: @Mysticial - The privilege is at 5 rep.

Comment: @TravisJ the "programming questions" might not be relevant any more as this site as the normal meta rules and requires a minimum of 5 rep to post. A poor question asker who's question blocked isn't likely to have enough rep to ask here. The other two are probably still relevant.

Comment: @ChrisF - People who post programming questions here tend to do it on accident, and most are first time users. I think that is because they don't realize they are on meta versus main. However, I would be willing to bet that forking off MSE didn't change any of that workflow.

Comment: @TravisJ = most of the people who posted here in the past (when it was a separate site) did so because they were prevented from asking on SO - hence the close reason.

Comment: @ChrisF - That makes sense as well. Will post-banned people be prevented from posting here now that this is a "proper" meta?

Comment: @TravisJ - that's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: @TravisJ given my experience on Programmers Meta (example [1](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/) [2](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5301/) (and others can be found without too much more of a search)), post banned users with sufficient reputation certainly can post on the persite meta.  Remember, it only takes one upvote or an accepted answer on *any* answer for someone to ask here.

Comment: @MichaelT - Given that, do you still receive programming questions on your meta?

Comment: @TravisJ yep - http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/how-to-properly-design-classes http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/presentation-tool-techniques-for-showcasing-your-work are two of 'em (deleted - read the slugs).  Not programming - but questions that should have been asked (and closed) on the main site instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should the new default off-topic close reason be?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250041/what-should-the-new-default-off-topic-close-reason-be)